# How do I change the selection color of a dropcap?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I ran into what appears to be a weird bug in chrome.

```css
.dropcap {
  font-size: 150%;
}

section p::first-letter {
  font-size: 150%;
  /*@apply dropcap*/
}

*::-moz-selection, .dropcap::-moz-selection {
  background: #f7941d !important;
}
*::selection, .dropcap::selection {
  background: #f7941d !important;
}

/* *::-moz-selection {
  background: #f7941d !important;
}
*::selection {
  background: #f7941d !important;
} */
```

```html
<section>
<p>hello world</p>
</section>
```

[image: screenshot of problem]

I've tried adding `!important` and targeting all elements `*`, targeting the `dropcap` class, etc. My setup is with tailwind and jekyll, but this bug appears in plain HTML, CSS & JS.

I'm wondering how to change the selection color (other than individually adding a `dropcap` class to every single starting character in every paragraph on the website)

Some more examples of this bug:

Chrome:
[image: chrome screenshot]

Firefox:
[image: firefox screenshot]

Deleting lines 5-8 (styles applied to first-letter) in chrome:
[image: chrome deleting first letter styles]
The dropcap is still a larger font-size, but the selection color now works. I'm wondering why this is and if I can somehow style dropcaps without screwing up the selection color or adding a span with a class to every single first character of every single paragraph on every single page of the website.

Comment: I'm not clear what this has to do with dropcaps (in the CSS sense) - is it to do with first-letter and selection not somehow combining?

Comment: styling the first letter reverts the selection color back to browser default, but only for that letter for some reason. this seems like a bug in chrome to me

Comment: Agreed - just tested in FF on Windows10 and it's fine as you say. Nothing seems to be able to persuade Chrome to re-color the background on selection of the first-letter.